# Laravel 5.2 curl_init() throwing error "Call to undefined function"

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I am trying to use FCM in laravel using curl but I am getting error. First I have written one php code in one of my cotroller which is :

```
$first_name = $request->input('first_name');
      //FCM api URL
      $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
      //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
      $server_key = 'AIzaSyA1RyuAGGPASh_flFCwiyd9ZHEMYlhQOho';
   $target = "r_token";
      $fields = array();
      $fields['data'] = $first_name;
      if(is_array($target)){
        $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
      }else{
        $fields['to'] = $target;
      }
      //header with content_type api key
      $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key='.$server_key
      );

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
```

And I am trying to run this code in my controller using laravel 5.2 but I am getting this error:

```
  FatalErrorException in WebKyoController.php line 52:
   Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()
```

I have tried : sudo apt-get install php-curl and apache restart but still I am getting error. I just want to know what do I need to do.

Comment: did you also tried `sudo apt-get install curl` also tell your Operating and version?

Comment: no I haven't tried this sudo apt-get install curl I am using ubuntu 14.04. It says curl is already installed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem I was having php 7 installed and it was not working. But I have removed php 7 and installed php 5 and then I run these commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install curl
 sudo service apache2 restart
 sudo apt-get install php5-curl
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Above commands did the trick for me. I don't know why it was not working on php 7

Comment: Its not about trick, its mean your curl module was not install... and by above commands its installed

Comment: This happens because I was having php 7 and I was installing php5 curl

Comment: I have installed the curl and my push notifications is working fine from another controllers, but after doing the same thing from my websocket controller for chat application its giving the same above error as the question asked. My laravel is 5.2 and i m using Ratchet
WebSockets

Comment: This answer is side-stepping the problem and not addressing it. Consider marking my answer as the answer for the community @NilaySingh.

Answer (score 15):

I stumbled across this answer, so just in case another hapless soul follows, please try the following that worked for me.

1. Find out the version of PHP running

`# php -v
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS ) ...`

**In this case, I have PHP 7.0**

2. Install Curl for your version of PHP

`sudo apt install php7.0-curl`

3. To instantly apply this installation run

`sudo service apache2 restart`

4. Run your code again and see if it no longer errors on Curl.

Answer (score 0):

not knowing version php

**sudo service apache2 restart**

**sudo apt-get install php-curl**